# AR Mobile Games using live camera

Tags: android, ios, html, sdk, augmented-reality

i wanna start working on developing a games like :

1. Mosquito AR Games : http://www.makayama.com/mosquitoes.html
2. DriodShooting : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kU9qsUJWzgI

the app use the camera and radar for spotting the object and hit it using touch what is the best SDK or platform or programming model to execute similar game targeting android and ios

Your help and advice is highly appreciated

thanks for all in advance

Comment: Hi, what about search for it in the internet? I am sure you will find many info about it.

Comment: thanks for your reply i look over the internet and i see this is the best place to exchange experiences, by the way i was not looking for information more than help and advice to hook the right way thanks alot for your reply again and sorry if i waste your time reading it

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ivan that this question is too broad to be handled here. But anyway, here are a few things to consider for the Android platform:

If you want to make use of 3D graphics (OpenGL) then you might run into a bottleneck, because for the time being you cannot have the live camera preview and an OpenGL surface view simultaneously on the same screen. Problem is that the so called SurfaceView (which is used for OpenGL rendering and the camera live preview) is not designed to be layered on top of each other. So you can get unexpected results when it comes to the display order (3D graphics rendered *behind* the video preview).

There are two solutions for this problem though:

1. You don't use 3D graphics and resort to rendering 2D objects on top of the camera preview
2. You do use 3D graphics but then you have to capture the camera preview, convert the YUV encoded data into RGB (which is problematic on some devices because of some non-standard compliant customizations of the encoding) and load that data into an OpenGL texture to be displayed on a rectangular primitive. The problem with that approach is: a lack of speed because of the additional processing overhead and most likely you need to scale down the camera preview texture because of limitations related to OpenGL.

Furthermore you need to make yourself familiar with [capturing motion sensor data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) for calculating a device rotation matrix that can be used for transforming the overlay graphics / virtual objects.

If your AR app is supposed to "interact" with the captured live video stream you run into the next bottleneck problem. That completely depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to recognize human faces, certain shapes, barcodes etc... whatever the requirement is, a Java implementation may be too slow for that and you need to resort to writing C code using the NDK (out of experience with different handsets you gain way more speed when it comes to image processing). And that's the next topic you need to cover. You also need to make yourself familiar with image processing. But first of all: create a specification. You need to know what you actually need for your AR app.

Some modern AR apps also resort to live streaming the captured video data to a server that has more processing power available for shape / image recognition.

You can read [this master's thesis](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/teaching/sada/sadalink/reports/biwi_00339.pdf) about the topic for more information.

So the bottom line is that AR apps can become really ambitious projects which involve a huge range of different technologies and disciplines.

Comment: You've clearly put a lot of thought into this answer, but I'd like to point out that even with the limited processing power of an Android app, it isn't very hard to write a decent AR app. Capturing sensor data is a easy job for someone even remotely familiar with Android, and libraries like AndAR make it very easy to have overlays that are rendered in 3 dimensions. Granted having more than two moderately detailed ones on the screen at a time is a performance killer, but it is possible.

Comment: thanks for that much of information i was thoght it more easy using low end sdk thats mean i have to look more into the details of your answer, thanks alot for your effort

Comment: After trying to write one, I agree with the above answer.  Many current devices do not have enough power (CPU/GPU), and there are lag issues where the screen is augmented, and some things work great, but in lower memory moments they run horribly, it can be costly to support.